# 94 Jeep 5.2 crank no start

Tags: engine, jeep, grand-cherokee, cranks-wont-run

I've owned my Grand Cherokee Laredo 10 years I love my Jeep let me explain why!! 2 days before it died while I was driving I couldn't go over 35 when I applied gas it would Studdard backfire and lose power so I went in to investigate I found that the EGR valve module was completely fried on replacing it one of the bolts was loose replacing that I figured that was the problem I got it to run when I applied gas it would die, here's what I figured she's 24 years old time for some new parts so I replaced crank sensor fuel pump coil ECM spark plugs cap Rota wires new vacuum lines PVC valve I'm still getting the same results she starts wants to run it dies when you give it fuel, so I took the throttle body of pull speed sensor indicator motor cleaned everything put it back together runs but dies when you hit gas my question is why won't it run? Could the alarm system have something to do with it? I've checked the code several time I reset it and checked it it's still coding 12 / 55

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If I'm reading the codes right, 12 pops when the battery has been disconnected in the past 50 key offs; 55 pops when the drive cycle hasn't completed yet. Neither of these are going to be an issue with it running. I have no idea about the alarm system. Overall, it sounds like a throttle position sensor isn't working correctly. Also, could you PLEASE edit your question and put some syntax in there. The run on sentence is VERY hard to read.

Comment: Hey Paulster2,  If there was a problem with the throttle position sensor wouldn't that show up on my codes I'm so sick of guessing and I know the alarm kills everything yes

Comment: No, not necessarily. You can test your TPS to see if it has full range of motion. If the engine doesn't want to run off idle, it would seem to me this is the first place I'd start looking.

Comment: dying when you give it gas makes me think of fuel pressure. Have you put a pressure gage on it?

Comment: I agree with the tps. However if your car has a bad maf that could also be why it dies. Reason being the ecu can’t increase fuel delivery to match the a/f ratio for the air coming into the engine, and it thus dies. Tldr check your maf and tps, and if it’s not those then check spark plugs (the gap) and fuel pressure in that order

Comment: Could also be the opposite, where when you give it more gas, it can't deliver enough air and the mixture becomes too rich to burn. Check your spark plugs. Since they are new, any issues should be obvious. If they are dry but burnt looking, you are running too lean. If they have have any dark residue or fouling, then you are running too rich.

Comment: my fuel pressure is normal, I replaced every sensor on the throttle body, it wants to start but it won't run I can smell gas as some people may call it gas wash. Is it possible it jump tooth and I'm out of time, I'm running out of options and also running out of putting new parts

Comment: @sjfklsdafjks I'm pretty sure those engines are speed density and don't use a MAF. OP what is normal fuel pressure? Numbers please. Do a TPS sweep and make sure the MAP sensor reads correctly KOEO and under different levels of vacuum. Are the O2 sensors switching? How about other sensors? You need to stop replacing parts and do some multimeter work. If you don't already have one buy a service manual.

Comment: @Ben - KOEO is "Key On Engine Off", correct?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 correct sir.

Comment: Hey guys, I checked the codes again it code it out 12 map sensor too much voltage not enough, as a new sensor I returned it they told me it was the wrong one in the Box. I installed the new one plugged it in Hook the battery backup. I did a code it came back 12 again could it be possible that was the wrong one in the Box or could I have another problem somewhere down the line. Is there a relay or fuse for the map sensor or does the ECM control the map sensor I am getting power to the sensor could be another bum sensor.

Comment: Hey Ben, on my engine it does not have not one O2 sensor I know I thought that to be strange but that particular year they did not use them however did did use one map sensor that's it.

Comment: I'm getting 40 PSI and she climbs when I crank

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having issues with that, I put a fishing weight on my throttle cable. That will keep it idling for you. My 94 is cantankerous too, and in the winter doesn't like the throttle cable cable throttled. Seriously, put a fishing weight on your throttle cable. Works great.